# C program complies but screen on console remains black

Tags: c, linux, debugging, console

I was writing a C program that would read and merge 3 files together (program not complete yet), however, as I was testing I realized the program compiles but the screen on the console remains blank!

Any help is appreciated, especially why is it blank?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{  
    printf("test");
    //open three files for merging
    FILE *fp1 = fopen("american0.txt","r");
    FILE *fp2 = fopen("american1.txt","r");
    FILE *fp3 = fopen("american2.txt","r");

    printf("test");
    //open file to store the result
    FILE *fpm = fopen("words.txt", "w");

    //creating an array to save the files data
    char c;
    char mergedFile[50];

    //checking to make sure files are being read
    if(fp1 == NULL && fp2 == NULL && fp3 == NULL && fpm == NULL)
    {
        printf("Could not open one or all of the files.\n");
        printf("Exiting program!");
        exit(0);
    }
    printf("test");
    //initializing counter values

    //inserting data from file into an array
    while ((c = fgetc(fp1)) != EOF)
    {
        fputc(c, mergedFile);
    }
    while ((c = fgetc(fp2)) != EOF)
    {
        fputc(c, mergedFile);
    }
    while ((c = fgetc(fp3)) != EOF)
    {
        fputc(c, mergedFile);
    }

    printf("%s",mergedFile[0]);
    printf("test");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `fputc` requires a `FILE*` as the second argument. How on *earth* did you get this to even *compile* when passing `mergedFile`, declared as `char mergedFile[50];` to those function calls ? Shouldn't those all use `fpm` ? From what I see, `mergedFile` is pointless to have in this code *at all*. Removing it and all it's usages would also fix `printf("%s",mergedFile[0]);`, which makes no sense itself, as `%s` requires a `const char*`, and you're passing a `char` to that `printf` invoke.

Comment: Well I [compiled and ran it](https://ideone.com/3FRKiH) and it did print stuff out, not sure what might be going wrong on your end. Don't take this wrong, as this feels like a stupid question to ask, but did you actually run it after compiling? Compiling will not execute the program, it will just produce a program that you can execute.

Comment: I feel like it is something minor and stupid that I'm doing that's causing this, However, I compile the program, all the warnings print out and when I run it the using "./a.out" it doesn't print out anything

Comment: I also just put the printf("%s", mergeFile[0]); as a test statement which I realized was wrong, but thanks for pointing out the issue with the mergedFile in the while statements :)

Comment: I believe the issue was with me passing mergedfile in the while loops, thank you for your help

Comment: @mahdi Correct. Change `mergedFile` to `fpm` in your while loops and it will work. The fact that C only gave you a warning in that case doesn't mean that the program will be OK; the problem is a serious one. Also, `printf("%s",mergedFile[0]);` will seg fault at run time; try `printf("%s", mergedFile)`. You should also call `fclose` on all your open files before exiting.

Comment: `fgetc` returns an `int`, not a `char`: `int fgetc ( FILE * stream )`. You are probably suffering a truncation bug and `c` never takes the value of `EOF` because it is too small a datatype. So you never escape the first `while` loop. You should probably compile with `-Wall` to help catch some of the mistakes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Error** --> `fputc` requires a file pointer as it's second argument rather than an array: `int fputc ( int character, FILE * stream );`

Points to be taken care of:

1. The size of array should be large enough to contain all the data from these files.
2. Take care of the format specifier and what it requires in a `char` array.
3. What if size of array is less than total size of all files? - Error handling
4. What if files to be read/written into are in some other directory?

Here is a minimal corrected version:

```
     #include <stdio.h>
     #include <stdlib.h>
     #define MAX 1000     //ADDED NEW

     int main()
     {  
         //open three files for merging
         FILE *fp1 = fopen("american0.txt","r");
         FILE *fp2 = fopen("american1.txt","r");
         FILE *fp3 = fopen("american2.txt","r");

         //open file to store the result
         FILE *fpm = fopen("words.txt", "w");



         //creating an array to save the files data
         int c;                             
         int i=0;
         char mergedFile[MAX]={0};           //MODIFIED & INITIALIZED           

         //checking to make sure files are being read
         if(fp1 == NULL && fp2 == NULL && fp3 == NULL && fpm == NULL)
         {
             printf("Could not open one or all of the files.\n");
             printf("Exiting program!");
             exit(0);
         }
         //initializing counter values

         //inserting data from file into an array
         while (((c = fgetc(fp1)) != EOF)&&(i<MAX))  //MODIFIED
         {
             mergedFile[i++]=c;                      //MODIFIED
         }
         while (((c = fgetc(fp2)) != EOF)&&(i<MAX))  //MODIFIED
         {
             mergedFile[i++]=c;                      //MODIFIED
         }
         while (((c = fgetc(fp3)) != EOF)&&(i<MAX))  //MODIFIED
         {
             mergedFile[i++]=c;                      //MODIFIED
         }

         printf("%s",mergedFile);                    //MODIFIED

         return 0;

     }
```

Comment: Better to use `int c;` than `char c;` to properly handle the typical 256 + 1 different results from `fgetc()`.

Comment: I know you were copying OP's code, but I think that `if` statement checking for file opening success should be `||` not `&&` since there will be a problem later if any file didn't open, not just if all didn't open.

Comment: @pstrjds OP has written in that `if` block in the `printf` statement which points that if all the files open successfully then only proceed further.

Comment: @user10334659 - I know that is what the OP has written (which is why I prefaced my comment with that), but since you are fixing the code I figured it was worth pointing out. As written it will only be true if *all* of the file open calls fail. If even one of them is successful the code will continue, which will cause problems later.

Comment: @pstrjds is correct. The error message `printf("Could not open one or all of the files.\n");` indicates `||` should be used; not `&&`.

Comment: @jww Initially I thought the same but then I felt maybe there is some constraint OP might have to be able to use all of them or none at all. So, I left it to the OP. Sure the program needs at least one file pointer to read (function) and one to write.

Comment: Thank you so much for all your help. this cleared up a lot of confusion!

Comment: @mahdi if it helped it then you can accept the answer https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: for sure, my bad just forgot to do it